# What would be the reasons for the exclusion of the UK and others from the Indian e-Visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, india, visa

*This is a follow-up to this [Travel question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/177021/118049)*

The UK, Canada, China and others have been excluded from the Indian e-Visa program when reintroduced in October 2021.

I'd assume this has been done to force those countries to implement faster and less cumbersome visa process for Indian nationals, but I wonder if there are other reasons.

Comment: Is there any complaint from these countries?

Comment: Canada's refusal to take action against anti-India elements in Canada seems one probable reason; but in line with "proportionate response" -  the reason given in the question is better suited.

Comment: @r13 [FM Truss raises visa issue](https://publictechnology.net/articles/news/pm-%E2%80%98raised-concerns%E2%80%99-over-uk%E2%80%99s-e-visa-exclusion-last-visit-india#:~:text=The%20new%20prime%20minister%20Liz%20Truss%20used%20her%20last%20visit%20to%20India%20to%20raise%20the%20concerns%20of%20British%20citizens%20impacted%20by%20the%20Indian%20government%E2%80%99s%20decision%20to%20remove%20the%20UK%20from%20its%20e%2DVisa%20programme.)

Comment: @whoisit I doubt this is the only reason, non-excluded countries most of the time have as cumbersome of a visa process than the excluded countries (US, Ireland...)

Comment: @whoisit Wow, that is a lone list with a resigned PM on it :)